# Parsing jQuery AJAX response

Tags: ajax, jquery

I use the  following function to post a form to via jQuery AJAX:

```js
$('form#add_systemgoal .error').remove();
var formdata = $('form#add_systemgoal').serialize();
$.ajaxSetup({async: false});  
$.ajax({     
    type: "POST",
    url: '/admin/systemgoalssystemgoalupdate?format=html',
    data: formdata,
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);   
    },
});
```

It posts fine but I cannot parse the respons, it logs to console as follows

```js
{
    "success": 1,
    "inserted": {
        "goal_id": "67",
        "goalsoptions_id": "0",
        "user_id": "0",
        "value": "dsfdsaf",
        "created": "2013-06-05 09:57:38",
        "modified": null,
        "due": "2013-06-17 00:00:00",
        "status": "active",
        "actions_total": "0",
        "actions_title": "sfdgsfdgdf",
        "action_type": "input",
        "points_per_action": "1",
        "expires": "2013-06-11 00:00:00",
        "success": 1
    }
}
```

which I believe is the response I am looking for.

However when I try to do `alert(data.success);` or any of the other members of the response object it is `undefined`.

Any advice appreciated.

Comment: `dataType: 'json'`. Did you put `?format=html` parameter intentionally? What does it mean?

Comment: If your AJAX Url returns a content header referring to JSON, you don't even need to $.parseJSON(yourdata), as jQuery would automatically do so by default. I do that, and in every response I also have a custom status code. This way you can easily verify if happened what you expected.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

calling

```
var parsed_data = JSON.parse(data);
```

should result in the ability to access the data like you want.

```
console.log(parsed_data.success);
```

should now show '1'

Comment: Don't parse json after it has been received. Indicate `dataType: 'json'` in your original request and you will get json, not text.

Answer (score 16):

```
 $.ajax({     
     type: "POST",
     url: '/admin/systemgoalssystemgoalupdate?format=html',
     data: formdata,
     success: function (data) {
         console.log(data);
     },
     dataType: "json"
 });
```

Answer (score 6):

Imagine that this is your Json response

```
{"Visit":{"VisitId":8,"Description":"visit8"}}
```

This is how you parse the response and access the values

```
    Ext.Ajax.request({
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    url: 'api/fullvisit/getfullvisit/' + visitId,
    method: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (response, request) {
        obj = JSON.parse(response.responseText);
        alert(obj.Visit.VisitId);
    }
});
```

This will alert the VisitId field

Answer (score 4):

you must parse JSON string to become object

```
var dataObject = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
```

so you can call it like:

```
success: function (data) {
    var dataObject = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
    if (dataObject.success == 1) {
       var insertedGoalId = dataObject.inserted.goal_id;
       ...
       ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using `$.ajax`, and not `$.getJSON`, your return type is plain text. you need to now convert `data` into a JSON object.

you can either do this by changing your `$.ajax` to `$.getJSON` (which is a shorthand for `$.ajax`, only preconfigured to fetch json).

Or you can parse the `data` string into JSON after you receive it, like so:

```
    success: function (data) {
         var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
         console.log(obj);
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `parseJSON`. Look at the [doc](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/)

```
var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
```

Something like this:

```
$.ajax({     
    type: "POST",
    url: '/admin/systemgoalssystemgoalupdate?format=html',
    data: formdata,
    success: function (data) {

        console.log($.parseJSON(data)); //will log Object

    }
});
```

Comment: It makes sense to fix the roots of the issue, not its consequences