# How to call another page in background in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a button in enroll.html . The code of the page is as follows :

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<META http-equiv=Content-Language content=en-us>
<META http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
<style TYPE="text/css">
    <!-- BODY               { font-family:arial,helvetica; margin-left:5; margin-top:0}
            A                   { color:#FF5500; text-decoration:underline}
            A:hover,A:active    { color:#0055FF; text-decoration:underline}
        -->
</style>
<Script Language="JavaScript">
<!--
function inStrGrp(src,reg)
{
    var regex=new RegExp("[" + reg + "]","i");
    return regex.test(src);
}

function check()
{   
    var uname=document.scan.elements[0].value
    var bError=false

    if (uname.length==0)
    {
        window.alert("Name is required.\n")
        return false
    }
    if (uname.indexOf("\\")>=0)
        bError=true

    if (inStrGrp(uname,'/.:*?"<>| '))
        bError=true

    if (bError)
    {
        window.alert('User name can not contain the following characters:\n \\/. :*?"<>|\n')
        return false
    }
    else 
        return true  
}
-->
</Script>

<title>Enroll New Fingerprint.</title>
</HEAD>
<BODY onload="document.scan.name.focus();">
<center>
<table border="0" width="800">
  <tr>
    <td width="100%" colspan="3">
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
      <p><u><b>Online Demonstration</b></u></p>
      <div align="center">
      <table border="1" width="100%" height="260">
        <tr>
          <td width="20%" align="center" rowspan="2">
                <p>&nbsp;</p>
                <p><font color="#0055FF">Enroll</font></p>
              <p><a href="logon.asp">Logon</a></p>
              <p>&nbsp;</p>
          </td>
          <td width="80%" height="30">
              <b><i>Enroll Finger</i></b>
          </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
          <td width="80%">
      <p>Thanks for your registration. You can enroll two fingers for the name you registered.</p>

      <form name="scan" method="POST" action="http://10.11.201.170/data/sultan/enroll.asp" onsubmit="return check()">
        <p>Please input your name: <input type="text" name="name" size="20">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>
        <p>If you want to enroll 2 fingers, please check the box. <input type="checkbox" name="chk2Finger" value="2">&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;
        <input type="submit" value="   Enroll   " name="btnEnroll"></p>
      </form>

            </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      </div>
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="100%" colspan="3">
      <p align="center"><small>Copyright © 2004 Futronic
      Technology Company Limited. All Rights Reserved.</small></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</center>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

When I press Enroll Button , I want to load a page named verify.asp in background . How can I do that ?

The code of verify.asp is as follows :

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<META http-equiv=Content-Language content=en-us>
<META http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
<style TYPE="text/css">
    <!-- BODY               { font-family:arial,helvetica; margin-left:5; margin-top:0}
            A                   { color:#FF5500; text-decoration:underline}
            A:hover,A:active    { color:#0055FF; text-decoration:underline}
        -->
</style>
<Script Language="VBScript" Src="GetInfo.vbs">
</Script>
<title>Enroll Fingerprint.</title>
</HEAD>
<BODY Onload="GetLearnModel()";>
<center>
<table border="0" width="800">
  <tr>
    <td width="100%" colspan="3">
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
      <p><u><b>Online Demonstration</b></u></p>
      <div align="center">
      <table border="1" width="100%" height="260">
        <tr>
          <td width="20%" align="center" rowspan="2">
                <p>&nbsp;</p>
                <p><a href="enroll.asp">Enroll</a></p>
              <p><a href="logon.asp">Logon</a></p>
              <p>&nbsp;</p>
          </td>
          <td width="80%" height="30">
              <b><i>Enroll Finger</i></b>
          </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
          <td width="80%">
        <Form name="scan" method="Post" action="famenroll2.asp?name=<%=Request("name")%>&check=<%=Request("check")%>&finger=<%=Request("finger")%>">
        <Input type="hidden" name="LearnModel" value="">
        <Input type="text" name="SlNo" value="">
        </Form>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
            <p><font size="5" color="#ff0000"><%=Request.Form("SlNo")%></font><font size="5">&nbsp;&nbsp;Enroll Successfully!</font></p>
            </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      </div>
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="100%" colspan="3">
      <p align="center"><small>Copyright © 2004 Futronic
      Technology Company Limited. All Rights Reserved.</small></td>
  </tr>
</table>
 <% Dim Conn,strSQL,objExec,NumOfRecords,se_name,finger
            cust_no=Request.QueryString("name")
            Set Conn = Server.Createobject("ADODB.Connection")  
            Conn.Open "Driver={Oracle in XE};DBQ=xe;UID=biotpl;PWD=biotpl;"           

            'Query for the customer entry in FP_ENROLL Table
            strSQL2 = "INSERT INTO TEST  values(1,'OS')" 

                Set objExec = Conn.Execute(strSQL2)

            'Query for the no of fingers to be taken for a customer in FP_FINGER_SETUP Table                  
            'Set objExec = Conn.Execute("select FINGURE_NO NoF from BIOTPL.FP_FINGER_SETUP where USER_TYPE=" & Request.QueryString("cust_type") )  
            'NumOfFingers = objExec("NoF")

            'Conn.Close()  
             Set objExec = Nothing  
             Set Conn = Nothing  
 %>
</center>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: what do you mean by load a page in Background??can you clarify a littile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an Id in this Line

```
<input type="submit" value="   Enroll   " name="btnEnroll">
```

So it becomes :

```
<input type="submit" value="   Enroll   " id="buttonEnroll" name="btnEnroll">
<div id="result"></div>
```

and Than Write this Script

```
    <script>
       $("#buttonEnroll").on('click',function(e){
           e.preventDefault();
           $( "#result" ).load( "verify.asp" );
           alert("Page loading completed");  
       });
    </script>

#result is for loading that page in result id div.
```

Hope Helps !

Add this inside your header tag

```
<script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"   integrity="sha256-a23g1Nt4dtEYOj7bR+vTu7+T8VP13humZFBJNIYoEJo="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Where will I put ajax/test,html page ?

Comment: I just changed it verify.asp , you can change to your desired page and load it to result div

Comment: Please give an alert message so that I can understand that the loading of the page is completed

Comment: Okay Changed, Anything else

Comment: But the action of the form is 10.11.201.170/data/sultan/enroll.asp . So when I click Enroll button , the page redirects to 10.11.201.170/data/sultan/enroll.asp . How can I stop this ?

Comment: <script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"   integrity="sha256-a23g1Nt4dtEYOj7bR+vTu7+T8VP13humZFBJNIYoEJo="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script> Add this inside your header

Comment: Still the page redirects to 10.11.201.170/data/sultan/enroll.asp

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110212/discussion-between-hemanjosko-and-osimer-pothe).

Comment: How can I understand that the loading of page is completed ?

Answer (score 1):

[Ajax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/AJAX) can be used to load a page in background. [jQuery supports AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) functionality and it is easier than what described in the first link. If your intention is to Verify an enrollment, you need to parse the reply coming out of the AJAX request. An earlier answer on parsing can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16935711/parsing-jquery-ajax-response).

The essential steps are

1. Add an id to your form submit button (say 'enroll')
2. Include jQuery JavaScript library to your project by adding the following in the header
   `< script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>‌`​

3.Within script tag, use a similar methodology as below.

```
$("#enroll").click(function(){ 
     $.ajax({
        url: "verify.asp", 
        success:   function(result){ 
                      /* Parse the result and do whatever you want to do here */
        }
      });
});
```

Comment: @C.Bandara Please update your answer instead of adding code as a comment. Your answer is marked as Low Quality and may be deleted in the near future if it stays like this.

Comment: Please don't recommend w3schools.com: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280478/why-not-w3schools-com

Answer (score 0):

```js
//1st way::

function doFunction(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
  //here you can load verify.aspx by using 
   $("#resultdiv").load("verify.aspx", {}, function (data) {
    alert("loading complete");  
   });
}


//2nd way:
//By using ajax call

$('#enroll').on('click', 'input[type="submit"]', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
   $.post('http://mywebsite/verify.aspx',{ 'data': $('#txt_search').val() } ,function(data) {
     console.log(data); // this would show you the returned data.
   });
});
```

```html
You can do it in 2ways:

HTML:

1st way::
=========
Add onclick to your enroll button.
<input type="submit" value="Enroll" onclick="doFunction();" id="enroll" name="btnEnroll"></p>
<div id="resultdiv">
  </div>

2nd way:
========
By using ajax call
```

Comment: But the action of the form is http://10.11.201.170/data/sultan/enroll.asp . So when I click Enroll button , the page redirects to http://10.11.201.170/data/sultan/enroll.asp . How can I stop this ?

Comment: Try my code Where i added e.preventDefault() for stop redirect thing

Comment: Where have you added e.preventDefault() ? I dont see anything .

Comment: In 2nd way, ajax call button click event

Comment: I am trying 1st way . can you add this in 1st way ? Still the page redirects to 10.11.201.170/data/sultan/enroll.asp

Answer (score 0):

Here is modified enroll.html with modified Js

```html
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<META http-equiv=Content-Language content=en-us>
<META http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
<style TYPE="text/css">
    <!-- BODY               { font-family:arial,helvetica; margin-left:5; margin-top:0}
            A                   { color:#FF5500; text-decoration:underline}
            A:hover,A:active    { color:#0055FF; text-decoration:underline}
        -->
</style>
<script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>

<title>Enroll New Fingerprint.</title>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<center>
<table border="0" width="800">
  <tr>
    <td width="100%" colspan="3">
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
      <p><u><b>Online Demonstration</b></u></p>
      <div align="center">
      <table border="1" width="100%" height="260">
        <tr>
          <td width="20%" align="center" rowspan="2">
                <p>&nbsp;</p>
                <p><font color="#0055FF">Enroll</font></p>
              <p><a href="logon.asp">Logon</a></p>
              <p>&nbsp;</p>
          </td>
          <td width="80%" height="30">
              <b><i>Enroll Finger</i></b>
          </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
          <td width="80%">
      <p>Thanks for your registration. You can enroll two fingers for the name you registered.</p>

      <form name="scan" >
        <p>Please input your name: <input type="text" name="txtName" size="20" id="txtname">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>
        <p>If you want to enroll 2 fingers, please check the box. <input type="checkbox" name="chk2Finger" value="2">&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;
        <input type="button" value="Enroll" name="btnEnroll" id="btnEnroll"></p>
      </form>

            </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      </div>
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="100%" colspan="3">
      <p align="center"><small>Copyright © 2004 Futronic
      Technology Company Limited. All Rights Reserved.</small></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</center>
</BODY>
</HTML>

<script type="text/javascript">

  function inStrGrp(src,reg)
  {
   var regex=new RegExp("[" + reg + "]","i");
   return regex.test(src);
  }

$(document).ready(function(){

 $('#btnEnroll').on('click',function(){
  var uname = $('#txtname').val();
  
  var bError=false

    if (uname.length==0)
    {
        window.alert("Name is required.\n")
        return false
    }
    if (uname.indexOf("\\")>=0)
        bError=true

    if (inStrGrp(uname,'/.:*?"<>| '))
        bError=true

    if (bError)
    {
        window.alert('User name can not contain the following characters:\n \\/. :*?"<>|\n')
        return false
    }
    else 
  var url = "enroll.asp?name="+uname;
  window.location = url;
        return true  

 
 
 });



});


</script>
```

change the url in the javascript code and put yours.If you url look like

> http://10.11.201.170/data/sultan/enroll.asp

this then

change the variable url in script section  like the following

```
var url = "http://10.11.201.170/data/sultan/enroll.asp?name="+uname;
```

and your enroll.asp will remain the same.

Hope that will help.