# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'series' of undefined highcharts

Tags: jquery, highcharts

This question is asked before but am unable to find the solution from there.

Here is my code

```
function draw_chart_1(date,tool)
    {
        $.ajax({
            type : "POST",
            url : "test",//servlet call

            data : {
                "date" : date,
                "tool" : tool
            },
            success : function(data) {
                 new Highcharts.Chart(data);
            }
        });
    }
```

ajax response is:

```
{  
   chart:{  
      zoomType:'xy',
      type:'column',
      renderTo:'container_1'
   },
   title:{  
      text:'title'
   },
   xAxis:{  
      tickInterval:1
   },
   yAxis:{  
      type:'logarithmic',
      minorTickInterval:0.1
   },
   plotOptions:{  
      line:{  
         dataLabels:{  
            enabled:true
         },
         enableMouseTracking:true
      }
   },
   yAxis:{  
      min:0,
      title:{  
         text:'# of count'
      }
   },
   tooltip:{  
      headerFormat:'<b>{series.name}</b><br />',
      pointFormat:'week = {point.x}, ASIN = {point.y}',
      credits:{  
         enabled:false
      }
   },
   series:[  
      {  
         name:'col 1',
         data:[  
            19640,
            19640,
            19640,
            19640,
            19640,
            19640
         ],
         pointStart:27
      },
      {  
         name:'col 2',
         data:[  
            4065,
            4065,
            4065,
            4065,
            4065,
            4065
         ],
         pointStart:27
      },
      {  
         name:'col 3',
         data:[  
            3854,
            3854,
            3854,
            3854,
            3854,
            3854
         ],
         pointStart:27
      },
      {  
         name:'col 4',
         data:[  
            1549,
            1549,
            1549,
            1549,
            1549,
            1549
         ],
         pointStart:27
      },
      {  
         name:'col 5',
         data:[  
            791,
            791,
            791,
            791,
            791,
            791
         ],
         pointStart:27
      },
      {  
         name:'col 7',
         data:[  
            223,
            223,
            223,
            223,
            223,
            223
         ],
         pointStart:27
      }
   ]
}
```

What is the wrong with this code?
I run on my page it is not working but if I replace the response instead of data in new Highcharts.Chart(data), it's working fine.

Comment: Did you try to parse json? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16935711/parsing-jquery-ajax-response

Comment: here I didn't use JSON to parse it. I have used as plain text.

Comment: Highcharts requires javascript object, so if your response is in plain text, you should parse it js object, if your response is in json format, you can use JSON.parse https://jsfiddle.net/wmqy0v9n/